# Lines on a GridView in ASP.Net, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, svg, gridview

I am trying to put a vertical line in front of a GridView in JavaScript to control intervals, but the line appears down the grid. Is it possible?

First I thought about the Cell borders, but it doesn't work. I am using svg to draw the line. The table is a GridView.

This is what I have:

[image: Table with line apart]

This is what I want:

[image: Table whit line]

I would like to know if it is possible to paint a control in front of another control. The line must be painted on client side (JavaScript).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use CSS (position) to place the SVG element on top of your grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem placing the SVG element on the top of the grid and setting his attribute height to 0. Thanks!